# Using SQL Alias to change Database Server name for SP2013 Farm

Tags: database-connection, database-server, sql-alias

I need a temporary workaround,

I have a farm SharePoint configured and running, it's pointing to DNS name of a Database Server, let's say `server01.domain.com`. I need the farm to point temporarily to a different DB server that contains all the copies of the config databases.

- First question, can I change the DB server name?
- Since I think the easy answer is no, can I register and alias using `server01.domain.com` as the alias name and the second server name as connection parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. Check those step by step manuals:

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=255

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2012/08/06/install-amp-configure-sharepoint-2013-with-sql-client-alias.aspx

Comment: ok, I will do it in this way

Comment: I have a question.  my central admin default datbase server is showing server.domain.com I moved all the required databases to newserver.  in cliconfg i gave alias as "server" and server name as "newserver".  what will happen if both of my database servers are active?  will it connect to original server or new one?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, changing the DB name on the SP side is a pain in the ***.

The best practice in this area is to use the tool *cliconfg* in order to point every SP server to a given DB server.
*cliconfg* allows you to create SQL alias at the OS level. Using it, you may create an alias *server01* pointing to the temp DB server *tempSQL*.
More info about *cliconfg* in the SP context: see step #3 of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2012/08/06/install-amp-configure-sharepoint-2013-with-sql-client-alias.aspx.

In all cases, creating an alias with *cliconfg* is a best practice as soon as you install your SP farm, to avoid such problems later.

Comment: thank you both!! Yes, aliases are the best solution when configuring a new environment, I've learned it the hard way :D